# Parallel: Run for loop in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to make my coed run in Parallel, which is shown as below,

```
for j in range(nj):
    for i in range(ni):
        # assign matrix coefficient
```

This is a very large matrix, which results in very low execution time, how can I run this kind of code in Parallel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the multiprocessing module could be useful to you. If you're not married to python check out LAPACK and ScaLAPACK

Answer (score 1):

You probably looking for `multiprocessing` module.

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def f(x,y):
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return x*y

p = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
res= []
for i in xrange(1,10):
  for j in xrange(1,10):
    res.append(p.apply_async(f, [i,j]))

for r in res:
  print r.get()
```